# How to show localized date units in a formatted string in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, date, localization, period

Let's say I have a period of days:

```
Period p = Period.ofDays(3);
```

And I want to format the period with the "days" label in the string to get this string as output:

```
// "3 days"
```

...but, I want to localize the "days" component, so I can't use a formatted string like the following, otherwise it will only ever appear correctly in English:

```
String.format("%d days", numberOfDays); // Won't localize 'days'
```

What APIs are there in Java/Kotlin/Android to represent a period of time, like hours, days, weeks, years in a locale? I would rather not localize those words by myself if I can let the API do it.

Comment: Time4J - [here](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/blob/master/base/src/main/resources/units/upattern_fr.properties), for example, is the French locale file for periods.

Comment: It’s not built into Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in one comment, you can use my lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) and use following code:

```
Period p = Period.ofDays(3);
Locale loc = Locale.ENGLISH; // or any other supported locale
String formatted = PrettyTime.of(loc).print(p); // 3 days
```

The tutorial also contains a [list of currently supported languages](http://time4j.net/tutorial/i18n.html). By the way, the Time4J-equivalent for `java.time.Period` would be `net.time4j.Duration<CalendarUnit>` if you are interested in other features like normalization or extended ISO-compatibility etc.

Note: If you are on **Android** then you should rather use the sister library [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) instead of Time4J but the presented code would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Kotlin `Duration` type with **localized formatting**, because I couldn't find a good solution, I **wrote one myself**. It is based on APIs provided starting in Android 9 (for localized units), but with a fallback to English units for lower Android versions so it can be used with lower targeting apps.

Here's how it looks like on the usage side (see Kotlin [Duration](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/-duration/) type to understand 1st line):

```kotlin
val duration = 5.days.plus(3.hours).plus(2.minutes).plus(214.milliseconds)

DurationFormat().format(duration) // "5day 3hour 2min"
DurationFormat(Locale.GERMANY).format(duration) // "5T 3Std. 2Min."
DurationFormat(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar").format(duration) // "٥يوم ٣ساعة ٢د"
DurationFormat().format(duration, smallestUnit = DurationFormat.Unit.HOUR) // "5day 3hour"
DurationFormat().format(15.minutes) // "15min"
DurationFormat().format(0.hours) // "0sec"
```

As you can see, you can specify a custom `locale` to the `DurationFormat` type. By default it uses `Locale.getDefault()`. Languages that have different symbols for number than romanic are also supported (via `NumberFormat`). Also, you can specify a custom `smallestUnit`, by default it is set to `SECOND`, so milliseconds will not be shown. Note that any unit with a value of `0` will be ignored and if the entire number is `0`, the smallest unit will be used with the value `0`.

This is the **full `DurationFormat` type** for copy & pasting (also available as a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/Jeehut/78534c27b24d78f14a3cbd3eebead861) incl. unit tests):

```kotlin
import android.icu.text.MeasureFormat
import android.icu.text.NumberFormat
import android.icu.util.MeasureUnit
import android.os.Build
import java.util.Locale
import kotlin.time.Duration
import kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime
import kotlin.time.days
import kotlin.time.hours
import kotlin.time.milliseconds
import kotlin.time.minutes
import kotlin.time.seconds

@ExperimentalTime
data class DurationFormat(val locale: Locale = Locale.getDefault()) {
    enum class Unit {
        DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, MILLISECOND
    }

    fun format(duration: kotlin.time.Duration, smallestUnit: Unit = Unit.SECOND): String {
        var formattedStringComponents = mutableListOf<String>()
        var remainder = duration

        for (unit in Unit.values()) {
            val component = calculateComponent(unit, remainder)

            remainder = when (unit) {
                Unit.DAY -> remainder - component.days
                Unit.HOUR -> remainder - component.hours
                Unit.MINUTE -> remainder - component.minutes
                Unit.SECOND -> remainder - component.seconds
                Unit.MILLISECOND -> remainder - component.milliseconds
            }

            val unitDisplayName = unitDisplayName(unit)

            if (component > 0) {
                val formattedComponent = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale).format(component)
                formattedStringComponents.add("$formattedComponent$unitDisplayName")
            }

            if (unit == smallestUnit) {
                val formattedZero = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale).format(0)
                if (formattedStringComponents.isEmpty()) formattedStringComponents.add("$formattedZero$unitDisplayName")
                break
            }
        }

        return formattedStringComponents.joinToString(" ")
    }

    private fun calculateComponent(unit: Unit, remainder: Duration) = when (unit) {
        Unit.DAY -> remainder.inDays.toLong()
        Unit.HOUR -> remainder.inHours.toLong()
        Unit.MINUTE -> remainder.inMinutes.toLong()
        Unit.SECOND -> remainder.inSeconds.toLong()
        Unit.MILLISECOND -> remainder.inMilliseconds.toLong()
    }

    private fun unitDisplayName(unit: Unit) = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        val measureFormat = MeasureFormat.getInstance(locale, MeasureFormat.FormatWidth.NARROW)
        when (unit) {
            DurationFormat.Unit.DAY -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.DAY)
            DurationFormat.Unit.HOUR -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.HOUR)
            DurationFormat.Unit.MINUTE -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.MINUTE)
            DurationFormat.Unit.SECOND -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.SECOND)
            DurationFormat.Unit.MILLISECOND -> measureFormat.getUnitDisplayName(MeasureUnit.MILLISECOND)
        }
    } else {
        when (unit) {
            Unit.DAY -> "day"
            Unit.HOUR -> "hour"
            Unit.MINUTE -> "min"
            Unit.SECOND -> "sec"
            Unit.MILLISECOND -> "msec"
        }
    }
}
```